# Woocommerce variation product price inside Add to cart button

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I use *"[Display price on add to cart button from the functions.php file in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51522141/display-price-on-add-to-cart-button-from-the-functions-php-file-in-woocommerce/51584094#51584094)"* answer code, that add price inside simple product.

But I want to improve this function and dynamically display chosen variation price inside button. With this code on variation product page it display only the lowest price.
Is there any solution?

**How add to cart button looks now *(no options chosen)*:**
[image: How add to cart button looks now(no options chosen)]

**How I want to be displayed:**
[image: How I want to be displayed]

Comment: This much more complicated and can only be done with additional Javascript / jQuery code as it's based on a an event on client side (but not on server side). See as an example: [Get selected variation price in jQuery on Woocommerce Variable products](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54928852/3730754) and [those related answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+%5Bjquery%5D+variation-product-price)

Comment: Thanks! You saved my project =)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it will be useful for somebody!
[Result. Add to cart button of variable product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBBdz.jpg)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_price', 20, 2 ); // Shop and other archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_price', 20, 2 ); // Single product pages
function custom_add_to_cart_price( $button_text, $product ) {
    // Variable products
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        // shop and archives
        if( ! is_product() ){

            $product_price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_price() ) ) );
            return $button_text . ' - From ' . strip_tags( $product_price );
        } 
        // Single product pages
        else {
            $variations_data =[]; // Initializing

        // Loop through variations data
        foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $variation ) {
            // Set for each variation ID the corresponding price in the data array (to be used in jQuery)
            $variations_data[$variation['variation_id']] = $variation['display_price'];
        }
        ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            var jsonData = <?php echo json_encode($variations_data); ?>,
                inputVID = 'input.variation_id';

            $('input').change( function(){
                if( '' != $(inputVID).val() ) {
                    var vid      = $(inputVID).val(), // VARIATION ID
                       vprice   = ''; // Initilizing

                    // Loop through variation IDs / Prices pairs
                    $.each( jsonData, function( index, price ) {
                        if( index == $(inputVID).val() ) {
                            vprice = Math.round(price); // The right variation price
                        }
                    });
                    // Change price dynamically when changing options
                    $( "button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt span" ).remove();
                    $(".single_add_to_cart_button").append("<span>" + " " + vprice + " ₴" + "</span>");
                }
            });
        });
        </script><?php
            return $button_text;
        }
    } 
    // All other product types
    else {
        $product_price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) );
        return $button_text . '  ' . strip_tags( $product_price );
    }
}
```