# Woocommerce variation product price didn't show anymore inside add to cart button

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using *[Woocommerce variation product price inside Add to cart button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61409848/woocommerce-variation-product-price-inside-add-to-cart-button/61416297#61416297)* answer code and it was working really well until today. I don't know why, but the price is no longer displayed in the "add to cart button".

As you can see [on my product page](http://www.jgh-webdesign.fr/HCPRESTIGE/produit/get-ready-micellar-spray/).

But, it work with product with no variations :/

This is my code (almost the same, just translate some words and change the currency)

```html
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_price', 20, 2 ); // Shop and other archives pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text', 'custom_add_to_cart_price', 20, 2 ); // Single product pages
function custom_add_to_cart_price( $button_text, $product ) {
    // Variable products
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ) {
        // shop and archives
        if( ! is_product() ){

            $product_price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product, array( 'price' => $product->get_variation_price() ) ) );
            return $button_text . ' - Dès ' . strip_tags( $product_price );
        } 
        // Single product pages
        else {
            $variations_data =[]; // Initializing

        // Loop through variations data
        foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $variation ) {
            // Set for each variation ID the corresponding price in the data array (to be used in jQuery)
            $variations_data[$variation['variation_id']] = $variation['display_price'];
        }
        ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(function($) {
            var jsonData = <?php echo json_encode($variations_data); ?>,
                inputVID = 'input.variation_id';

            $('input').change( function(){
                if( '' != $(inputVID).val() ) {
                    var vid      = $(inputVID).val(), // VARIATION ID
                       vprice   = ''; // Initilizing

                    // Loop through variation IDs / Prices pairs
                    $.each( jsonData, function( index, price ) {
                        if( index == $(inputVID).val() ) {
                            vprice = (price).toFixed(2); // The right variation price
                        }
                    });
                    // Change price dynamically when changing options
                    $( "button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt span" ).remove();
                    $(".single_add_to_cart_button").append("<span>" + " " + vprice + " €" + "</span>");
                }
            });
        });
        </script><?php
            return $button_text;
        }
    } 
    // All other product types
    else {
        $product_price = wc_price( wc_get_price_to_display( $product ) );
        return $button_text . '  ' . strip_tags( $product_price );
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody can help me ? It's look like the problem come from the var vprice, this code found the right ID and the right price, but didn't display it and I don't know why ...

Comment: In fact, as soon as I have another product display (similar, cross-sell, or product grid), it no longer works.