# WooCommerce variation product price inside Add to cart button issue on shop/archive page

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I'm trying to get the variation prices to displays in the Add to Cart button for WooCommerce and I've implemented [Woocommerce variation product price inside Add to cart button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61409848/woocommerce-variation-product-price-inside-add-to-cart-button/61416297#61416297) answer code.

This works great on both the single product page but seems to not work at all when there are more than 1 variation product on the shop/archive page.

The issue seems to be with the jQuery selectors `$('input')`, `$("button.single_add_to_cart_button.button.alt span" )`

It's trying to apply the changes to all instances of `button.single_add_to_cart_button`.

I'm wondering if it's possible to target the specific product inputs change and then update the `button.single_add_to_cart_button` for that specific product.

I've tried using the instance of `$(this)` but that has not worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Why was my question edited? This is 2nd time this has happened.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec would you possibly have the answer to my query? Happy to contact you directly if that's the case.

Comment: Removed because this is the code from an existing answer… We expected you to provide in your question your own real code attempt, which was not the case.